# Why does my armature stretch when moving/rotating

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm fairly new to Blender and don't really know the intricacies of how blender does things. I'm trying to rig this model. I have the body as an object and the head as a separate object. I have a simple armature setup.
[image]

When I rotate the head armature, the armature seems to stretch along with my mesh object. I don't know why this is happening. as I don't want any deformation on the object and should just rotate as a whole.
[image]

I've tried:

1. Playing with different vertex groups and weights
   (I've set a value of 1 to the head bone and 0 to all others)
2. Attaching the mesh object directly to the bone as a parent
3. Selecting/Deselecting the "Deform" option on the bone

Thanks

Comment: Probably, because the armature has unapplied, non-uniform scale, or the armature is ultimately parented to something that does.

Comment: since you didn't show us any useful information like armature settings and so on...pls provide blend file so we can check it out, thx

Comment: As Nathan says, select the armature in Object mode and press Ctrl A (Apply) > Scale and it should fix your problem

Comment: @moonboots Thanks boss, that indeed fixed it. If you don't mind can you quickly do a explanation what I just did?

Thanks

Comment: You must have scaled your armature before, we can see that the bones don't have their normal scale. If you do that it will stretch the mesh in an undesired way. In order to give  back a scale of 1:1:1 to your armature but keep its current size, you need to scale, see a tuto on this topic, maybe this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK0_FH7miEQ

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense since my armature looks like they're different sizes